# "Swagger: skipping unknown type" messages when using Composer REST Server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When starting the Composer REST Server , there are multiple lines that state "Swagger: skipping unknown type" before the server is started.

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Swagger: skipping unknown type "RegionCode".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "RegionCode".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "RegionCode".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "RegionCode".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "Type".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "Country".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "Status".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "JobType".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "CarType".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "Type".
Swagger: skipping unknown type "Country".
```

It looks like the concepts are being skipped when generating is done, although I am not sure why there are multiple skipping for the same concept.
Is this by design?

Comment: the message is a loopback message (for schema generation) - Composer REST server uses loopback 3 - not seen your model, but it may be where (in your model definitions) you are referencing the concepts mentioned in multiple places?

Comment: yes, these "types" are all Composer modelling concepts and thus I was wondering if this is by design of the Composer REST Server / Loopback generation

Comment: it is something that Loopback reports back (by design). Its just a warning msg.

Answer (score 0):

- After spending so much time i finally found the work around solution.
- Currently this package is not under proper maintenance i think so
  https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/400
  Still Open Issue.

But the work around solution is

Lock the package to 8.1.0 version like below
composer.json file

```
    "require": {
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "8.1.0",
```

Thanks