# Required Field Validator for Model (.cto file) in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a blockchain application using Hyperledger Composer.
This is a part of my model i.e. .cto file:

```
concept Address{
  o String addressId
  o String PersonInChargeFullName
  o String title
  o String address1
  o String address2 optional
  o String city
  o String country
  o String zipcode regex=/^\d{5}$/
  o String phone regex=/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$/
  o String email regex=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/
  o Boolean isActive default=true
}

abstract participant Company identified by companyId{
  o String companyId
  o String companyName
  o Address defaultAddress
}

participant OEM extends Company {
  o Address[] plants
}
```

From this [page](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/reference/cto_language), I understand that if we use **optional** as a field validator, which means that that field is optional, and others are not. Am I right?

Although, I have not made **PersonInChargeFullName** as optional, when I submit the data (for eg: `"PersonInChargeFullName": "",`) from composer-rest-server API, the transaction gets processed, without any error.

Please advise.

Comment: 1. correct. 2. have you restarted the REST server to take effect? The observable behaviour for an empty string should be as per -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4312 ie `instance is not valid`, ie a loopback validation error (Composer REST server is a loopback app). Example: (`Details: PersonInChargeFullName can't be blank (value: \"\")` . What version of Composer are you using?

Comment: 1. Thank you for the confirmation. 2. Yes, I have restarted the composer REST server and checked it, but still empty string is been processed. I am using the latest composer version which is 0.20, I think, I installed it from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html .

Comment: OK, just saw Address is a concept, I suspect this might be why behaviour is different (Composer REST Server uses loopback)  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626500/swagger-skipping-unknown-type-messages-when-using-composer-rest-server) as concepts are ignored during loopback schema generation for the business network,  could be validation for concepts is not generated.

Comment: Ok. I hope that concepts will be covered in upcoming updates. I will change the schema of the model then or will handle the validation in front end. Thank you.

Comment: validation for concepts gets generated, if we use regex. In the above example, zipcode, email and phone number are having validation in the API. It is only the required validation which is not working. I will use regex for them too. Will update, if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here option is little bit of different concept try running your code without `PersonInChargeFullName` field not as `PersonInChargeFullName = ""` but don't include it in json input i am pretty sure you will get error.